# Matlab: change value of field of a struct inside an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I would like to know the Matlab way of doing this:

I have an array of structs (Line) called lines.

Each Line looks like:

> ```
> point1: [1 128]
> point2: [218 128]
>  theta: -90
>    rho: -127
> ```

I need to subtract a value from all the point1(2) and point2(2) of all the lines in struct.

Comment: Can you develop more about your struct. It like Line.point1 = Array 2x1 ?

Comment: This is a great candidate for generating a lines class, with a method to subtract a scalar from that element of that field.

Comment: Yes Alexander, If I write that on the console I get ans = 1   128. They are the X and Y coords of the point

Comment: You want to do it without loop ?

Comment: Yea, if it's possible.

Comment: It's possible, see my solution.  ;)  Updated for point1(s).

Comment: Take into account that `arrayfun` may be slower than a `for` loop

Comment: Yea, thanks for that, I just did a small test and got 0.003689 seconds for arrayfun and 0.000715 seconds for for-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one-line solution for `point1` would use `arrayfun` and `setfield`/`getfield` as follows,

```
lineStructArray2 = arrayfun(@(x) (setfield(x,'point1',getfield(x,'point1')+[0 dy])), lineStructArray)
```

where `dy` is the value you want to add (negative for subtract) from `point1(2)`.  Make a similar command for `point2`.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is made like this :

```
myArray = [line line2];
```

So you have a struct array. You can't acces it with

```
myArray(:).point1(2);
```

So you have to create a loop

```
myStoringArray = [];
for it = 1:size(myArray,2)
  myStoringArray = [myStoringArray myArray(it).point1(2)];
end
```

Comment: And beware, a struct array must contain all same struct. So all your line need point1, point2, theta and rho define or at least set null.